# Can c++ armadillo find pairwise minimum of 2 vectors

Tags: c++, armadillo

I’m considering using armadillo for a project.  Was wondering if it has function to find minimum of two vectors,  element by element pairwise and store result in 3rd vector.

Comment: Have you tried looking it up online or *reading the documentation*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Armadillo supports [element-wise minimum for matrices and cubes](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#min_and_max), but not vectors:

```
min(A, B)
```

> For two matrices/cubes A and B, return a matrix/cube containing element-wise extremum values

However, as @mtall points out, [vectors are derived from matrices](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) in Armadillo. Since the [parameters are passed by reference](https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/blob/unstable/include/armadillo_bits/fn_max.hpp), it should work.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. You can use vectors directly. A vector in Armadillo is also a matrix. The vectors classes are in fact [derived](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) from the matrix class.

Comment: I think that min, max for V gives min or max element.

Comment: I did not write my question correctly,  instead of 2 vectors my actual problem is trying to do the pairwise minimum of two columns in a matrix and storing result in another column.  I think your answer should work for this.